# How to handle a unique dynamic ID in a JSON object?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, httprequest

I am new to json handling and i am using retrofit to query the API. This is the JSON i am getting from the API. The ID "f9dcf2ef-8647-46c1-b1cc-7e2bb6c3caa2" changes every time i change the username from the URL https://r6.apitab.com/search/uplay/{username}.

```
 {
  "status": 200,
  "foundmatch": true,
  "requested": "iishiro_o",
  "players": {
    "f9dcf2ef-8647-46c1-b1cc-7e2bb6c3caa2": {
      "profile": {
        "p_name": "IIShiro_o",
        "p_user": "f9dcf2ef-8647-46c1-b1cc-7e2bb6c3caa2",
        "p_platform": "uplay",
        "verified": false
      },
      "refresh": {
        "x": 0,
        "s": 0
      },
      "stats": {
        "level": 127
      },
      "ranked": {
        "kd": 1.27,
        "mmr": 2820,
        "rank": 15,
        "champ": 0,
        "NA_mmr": 0,
        "NA_rank": 0,
        "NA_champ": 0,
        "EU_mmr": 0,
        "EU_rank": 0,
        "EU_champ": 0,
        "AS_mmr": 2820,
        "AS_rank": 0,
        "AS_champ": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was using generated POJO classes to get my data but since the ID changes dynamically and i don't know the IDS. How will i be able to query the API to get data? To be honest, i just need to get the ID so that i can query the API to get more detailed data through this URL  https://r6.apitab.com/player/{ID} .

```
final Retrofit retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://r6.apitab.com/search/uplay/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

R6TabWireApi r6TabWireApi = retrofit1.create(R6TabWireApi.class);
Call<RainbowSixUser> call = r6TabWireApi.getUserId(userName);
```

[How my POJO looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJQPQ.png)

Comment: can you show this class `R6TabWireApi` ?

Comment: its the interface for retrofit. https://prnt.sc/rzwnj1

Answer (score 0):

Your Pojo for your example json could look like this:

```
class Pojo {

     // fields like status, foundmatch, etc.

     public Map<String, PlayerPojo> players;

     // other fields
}
```

That way you can just access `pojoInst.players.values()` to get a list of players.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i was trying to use your method but then i realised that using an autogenerated pojoClasses was the mistake and i made my own simple pojo till players thus only giving me the IDs. Then i will use regex and indexOf to get the ID and get my data.